# Problems using transfer in Solidity

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, cryptocurrency

```
function withdraw(uint amount) public returns (bool){
    
    uint cethAmount = amount;
    uint bosAmount = cethAmount * 11;
    
    require(bosAmount <= balances[msg.sender]);
    require(address(this).balance >= cethAmount);
    
    balances[msg.sender] -= bosAmount;
    totalSupply_ -= bosAmount;
    
    payable(msg.sender).transfer(cethAmount);
    return true;
}
```

This piece of code aims to take an unsigned integer as an input and send that amount back to the user.
The code executes up to line 7 (totalSupply_ -= bosAmount;), but after that no cTH is transferred and the output is not true.
This throws no errors also

Comment: 1) Does the (sender) contract have enough ETH to transfer the `cethAmount`? _(this is the most probable reason why the tx reverts)_ ... 2) It's possible that the `msg.sender` is a contract that doesn't have a `receive` or `fallback` function or that it reverts the transaction when they receive the ETH... 3) It's also possible that you're not sending enough `gas` with the transaction so that when you include the `transfer()` method, the tx fails due to insufficient gas.

Comment: @PetrHejda the require should check the contract has enough balance to return the transaction